# Trouble with references except on rebuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with two projects, A and B. A contains three classes, each in a different namespace, and B depends on and references A.

In B, I can use two of the classes in A, but it can't see the third namespace. The exception is if I do a rebuild of A, in which case the third namespace starts showing up in intellisense and everything works until the next time I do a full build or publish.

Any ideas? This is C# code in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have you created a project reference or an assembly reference? Make sure you picked the former and not the latter. If in doubt, remove the reference and recreate it.

Comment: Not allowed to use project references, unfortunately. What confuses me is that the other namespaces in the project work fine; it's just the one that doesn't.

Comment: Say what? Not allowed? Says who?

Comment: Says the people setting policy at the company I work for, I suppose. I know there's a technical reason, but I never got the details.

Comment: Then you need to tell us which kind of projects you have, because if A is a class library, then you **should** use a project reference when the two projects are in the same solution. Using an assembly reference, probably referencing the dll on disk in the output folder of the first project, is a recipe for problems, just like you discovered, but it is also **the incorrect thing to do**.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier to answer a more specific question. So I just take a shot from the hips...
Clashing namespaces can cause such an error. Intellisense can then resolve a method but you can't compile it. For example this seems correct, but won't compile:

```
namespace Business.Apartment.HR
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
namespace Apartment.HR.Area
{
    public class Class2
    {
    }
}
namespace Business.Apartment
{
    public class Caller
    {
        public Caller()
        {
            var c1 = new HR.Class1();
            var c2 = new Apartment.HR.Area.Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I had tried is renaming the troublesome namespace (from A.Fakes to A.UnitTest), but I got the same behavior. Except after doing a rebuild, it just doesn't show up in intellisense at all; when it does show up after a rebuild it compiles correctly.

Comment: @William Have you GACed any of your assemblies? In that case VS is picking up the GACed assemblies and not the latest code. Or maybe you referenced the assembly instead of the project?

Comment: Hmm. I haven't that I'm aware of, but I'll look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.